# grouping a character vector into new groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Trial [1]
GID       Trial pop   `1A-1145442` `1A-1158042`
<chr>     <chr> <chr>        <int>        <int>
GID421213 ES1   ES1-5           12           11
GID419903 ES1   ES1-5           22           12
GID3881   ES1   ES1-5           22           22
GID13646  ES1   ES1-5           12           12
GID418846 ES1   ES1-5           22           11
```

Here is a `dput` of it :

```
structure(list(GID = c("GID421213", "GID419903", "GID3881", "GID13646", 
"GID418846"), Trial = c("ES1", "ES1", "ES1", "ES1", "ES1"), pop = c("ES1-5", 
"ES1-5", "ES1-5", "ES1-5", "ES1-5"), `1A-1145442` = c(12L, 22L, 
 22L, 12L, 22L), `1A-1158042` = c(11L, 12L, 22L, 12L, 11L)), row.names = 
 c(NA, -5L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = 
 "Trial", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:4), group_sizes = 5L, 
 biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(Trial = "ES1"), row.names 
 = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Trial", drop = TRUE))
```

I want to perform a regrouping transformation into a new column from the Trial column just as I did in the past with the pop column using `regex` operations but now with `dplyr`. The Trial column consists of ES values from 1 to 38: I would like to group in this fashion ES1-3,ES3-6,ES7-9 and so forth using the `dplyr` package. I know I could start with `df >%> group_by(df,Trial)` but from there on I have no idea how I could operate.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if sample data had not just `ES1`. Also, how come 3 belongs two both ES1-3 and ES3-6? The part "and so forth" is not helpful either..

Comment: sorry ES1-3,ES4-6,ES7-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(pop2 = case_when(
    Trial == "ES1" | Trial == "ES2" | Trial == "ES3" ~ "ES1-3",
    Trial == "ES4" | Trial == "ES5" | Trial == "ES6" ~ "ES4-6"
  ))
```

Will return

```
    # A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   Trial [1]
  GID       Trial pop   `1A-1145442` `1A-1158042` pop2 
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>        <int>        <int> <chr>
1 GID421213 ES1   ES1-5           12           11 ES1-3
2 GID419903 ES1   ES1-5           22           12 ES1-3
3 GID3881   ES1   ES1-5           22           22 ES1-3
4 GID13646  ES1   ES1-5           12           12 ES1-3
5 GID418846 ES1   ES1-5           22           11 ES1-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `parse_number` from `readr`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cut(parse_number(Trial), 
                   breaks = seq(1, 38, by = 3), 
                   right = FALSE)) %>% 
  group_by(grp)
```

This pulls out the number from `Trial` then `cut`s to create a grouping variable, which it then groups by. `right=FALSE` indicates that the interval is closed on the left.

---

An edit based on a comment below.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cut(parse_number(Trial), 
                   breaks = c(seq(1, 34, by = 3) 38), 
                   right = FALSE),
                   include.lowest = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(grp)
```

Comment: Should this be parse_number(Trial)?

Comment: @EmilyKothe Yep, typo. Thanks!

Comment: your code is nice , the only thing I am trying to figure out now is how to create a uneven break for the last group (34,38]. it would be a break of 4 not 3. cheers

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini `include.lowest = TRUE` when `right = FALSE` means the final interval is closed at both ends. However, in this case, doesn't that mean `[34, 37]`? Hmmm. (`include.lowest = TRUE` when `right = TRUE` means the first interval is closed at both ends.)

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini A cludge would be to use `c(seq(1, 34, by = 3), 38)` with  `include.lowest = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
(df <- data.frame(Trial = paste0("ES", 1:10)))
#    Trial
# 1    ES1
# 2    ES2
# 3    ES3
# 4    ES4
# 5    ES5
# 6    ES6
# 7    ES7
# 8    ES8
# 9    ES9
# 10  ES10
```

We may, using base R, do

```
size <- 3
groups <- (as.numeric(substring(df$Trial, 3)) - 1) %/% size
(df$newCol <- sprintf("ES%d-%d", 1 + groups * size, size * (1 + groups)))
#  [1] "ES1-3"   "ES1-3"   "ES1-3"   "ES4-6"   "ES4-6"   "ES4-6"   "ES7-9"   "ES7-9"  
#  [9] "ES7-9"   "ES10-12"
```

Here `as.numeric(substring(df$Trial, 3))` gets the numeric part of `df$Trial` and converts it to a numeric vector. Subtracting 1 and using `%/%` then returns the group number for each element of `df$Trial`, starting from 0. Given a group number, we can easily construct a new column with `sprintf`.

`size` is the size of groups. E.g., setting `size <- 5` would give values `ES1-5`, `ES6-10`, and so on.